# What was added in Monument Valley+?

Tags: monument-valley

There is a new version of *Monument Valley* on Apple Arcade called [*Monument Valley+*](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/monument-valley/id1551940922). The description doesn't mention any new features, and the original game is still available for purchase.

How is Monument Valley+ different from the original Monument Valley?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AppleArcade/comments/mizswn/is_monument_valley_different_from_the_original/):

> It comes with the DLC chapters.

So the regular version + DLC should be the same as the Apple Arcade version.